# Why does a ball keep rolling?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

When a rigid ball rolls on a plane with no other forces, it is known that no friction applies and the ball keeps rolling. I was asked if this $F_{\text{friction}}=0\,$ can be derived from the usual law of static friction:

> Static friction applies in the opposite direction of the tangential part of the external force, with equal magnitude.

Of course, this must be applied to a small particle at the contact point of the ball and plane. The external force would be the force from the other particles in the rigid body, to maintain its shape. So, how could this be derived? I want a logically complete explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Static friction opposes impending relative motion between two surfaces (if relative motion actually occurs then we have kinetic friction). The external force being referred to is a force that has a component parallel to the ground such that it tries to slide the surfaces past each other.

The force acting on your point in contact with the ground in order to keep the object rigid acts upwards, i.e. with no horizontal component$^*$. Therefore this force does not "activate" any static friction.

If a ball is rolling on an (ideal) flat surface, and there is no external force acting on the ball itself in the horizontal direction, then there is no static friction force. Hence no torques or horizontal forces at all, and the ball will roll along at a constant speed.

---

$^*$ Let's show why this is the case. The easiest thing to do is just to consider moving along with the ball at its constant speed. Then you will just observe a particle undergoing uniform circular motion, and hence the acceleration must be directed upwards.

However, let's say you are still not convinced. Maybe you are resistant to changing your inertial frame of reference, and you want to see the argument done as you watch the ball roll by. The path a point on the outside of the circle traces out is called a [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid). The position vector as a function of time then for a point on the circle is given by
$$\mathbf r=R(\omega t-\sin\omega t)\hat x+R(1-\cos\omega t)\hat y$$
where $R$ is the radius of the circle, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the rotation, and we are looking at a point of the circle that starts touching the ground at the origin at $t=0$

Through simple derivatives, we can show that the velocity $\mathbf v$ and the accleration $\mathbf a$ are
$$\mathbf v=R(\omega-\omega\cos\omega t)\hat x+R(\omega\sin\omega t)\hat y$$
$$\mathbf a=R(\omega^2\sin\omega t)\hat x+R(\omega^2\cos\omega t)\hat y$$

The particle hits the ground every time $R(1-\cos\omega t)=0$ i.e., $t=2\pi n/\omega$ for any non-negative integer $n$. Plugging this time into our acceleration vector, we get
$$\mathbf a\left(t=\frac{2\pi n}{\omega}\right)=0\hat x+R\omega^2\hat y$$

Hence the acceleration only points upwards when the point is in contact with the ground.

Comment: Why is the force acting on the contact point upwards?? I was aware of the parallel part, I forgot to put it in my definition.

Comment: It is due to the centripetal acceleration as the particle moves in a circle

Comment: @Quasi07 Aditya beat me to it. But that is correct,

Comment: Yes I had this thought, but I don't think it is logically correct. The thing I'm trying to show is that there is no static friction, hence no angular acceleration. If there was angular acceleration, the acceleration wouldn't be pointing up. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Quasi07 My answer explains why there is no static friction. There is no force attempting to slide the surfaces past each other. It is equivalent to asking "Why does a book sitting in an upward accelerating elevator not have static friction on it? The book has the external force of the elevator acting upwards on it."

Comment: @Aaron But you just said that the reason why the force is upwards is because there is only centripetal acceleration, and that is because there is no static friction. That seems like circular reasoning to me. Also, I know that friction only applies opposing to the parallel part of external force. I made this clear in my first comment.

Comment: @Quasi07 I never employed such circular reasoning in my answer, but you are right. I will show you how the acceleration vector still points upwards for rolling without slipping at constant speed.

Comment: @Quasi07 I have included more information

Comment: @AaronStevens " Static friction opposes relative motion between two surfaces". Just a suggestion, but in order for the OP not to confuse static with kinetic friction, do you think it might be better to say that static friction opposes impending relative motion of an object with a surface?

Comment: @BobD I see what you mean. I will edit accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But isn't there still an ambiguity in this?  I believe the cycloid is a path of a point on a circle when the ball does not slip. Wouldn't this still be assuming the ball does not slip?

Comment: @Quasi07 I feel like you keep moving your goal posts here. What are you really wanting to know? Do you want to understand why there is no slipping, or do you want to understand why there is no static friction force? I have been going after the latter, but now you are asking about the former. Your main question, which focuses on static friction, asks nothing about how to show there is no slipping. If there was slipping then static friction would be out of the question, so this is why we have taken no slipping as an assumption.

Comment: Well, I thought the two were equivalent. Because if there is static friction for just a moment, the ball would slip. And if there is no static friction, there is no reason for the ball to slip. The primary goal was the former.

Comment: @Quasi07 Static friction means there is friction but no slipping between the surfaces. Are you getting confused with kinetic friction?

Comment: I don't think so.. My thought for another possibility is as follows: although it doesn't slip for that moment where static moment applies, after a short time the contact point changes, and because it can't still roll without sliding when there is static friction (this can be calculated with the laws of motion) it would start to slip and kinetic friction applies from that point.

Comment: @Quasi07 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95464/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-quasi07).

Answer (score 1):

There are two different points here:

1. The friction at the base of a rolling ball is static if we are in the case of a pure rolling. In fact the base point is istantaneously stationary, the image should be eloquent on this.

[image]
2. Static friction makes no work, because there is no displacement, so making no work it can't alter the speed of a system.

Sorry for the oversized image!